# How to call base class constructor new base(argT argV) when creating new obj()?

Tags: c++, oop, c++03

So I have a `base` class with a constructor that takes `(T V)`. I have inherited class `obj` that has a constructor `()` I would like to create something like

```
base * new_list_item = new obj()
```

But how to pass to obj base constructor value `T val;` in C++?

Comment: Please post the definitions of `obj` and `base`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the initialiser list:

```
class obj : public base {
public:
    obj(T v) : base(v)
    {}
};
```

Comment: and how shall I create an instance of it?

Comment: @myWallJSON: `new obj(v)` or `obj(v)`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Is there any way I could keep `obj` constructor defenition free from arguments? So that car that inherits from obj would not have to think about havind anething in its constructor?

Comment: @myWallJSON: Well, where is the `v` going to come from?

Comment: `v` comes from the main app (construction initiator)

Comment: @myWallJSON: That could mean a lot of different things.  But whatever it is, it needs to make its way to the `base` constructor somehow.  You could use `obj() : base(get_my_T())` where `get_my_T()` is some function that gets/calculates the relevant value from somewhere, I suppose.